# how to fix container configuration for C code

Tags: c, configuration, codeanywhere

I'm newbie in computer science.

I have only studied C language with Visual Studio.

I want to study C language using codeanywhere Because for

personal reasons nothing can be downloaded to my computer.

So, I sign up codeanywhere and make container but when I

run C code, I got some error.

The error is **"Run configuration not defined! Please open
Container config and define your run configuration."**

This is what I do in codeanywhere

[image: Make Container]

I made Container with C stack

[image: create file]

create file "hello.c"

[image: code]

this is code and run

[image: error]

and this is error display

[image: container configuration]

this is container configuration

I don't know how to fix this container configuration.

Please answer about that

thank you

Comment: I've never used codeanywhere, but it seems to me that the last picture already says what you should do: `\\ Delete next line and uncomment or change lines above`

Comment: Why don't you learn from a free copy of a good C book like [Modern C](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and then compile and run the code online with f.e. https://www.onlinegdb.com/ or https://godbolt.org/? Also what is the reason why you can't install a compiler on your machine? Is it the computer from somebody else and you don't be allowed to install anything?